# conveert dd.mm.yy into YYYYMM in Ingres db

Tags: sql, ingres

I have date as DD.MM.YYYY how I can convert it into YYYYMM 
tql CONVERT() function doesn't work in ingres MySQL  DATE_FORMAT also

Comment: SET date_format= 'german' comes to mind.

Comment: the problem i need to have it only in query  not  for whole DB

Comment: What version of Ingres are you using, and is the existing dd.mm.yyyy date stored as a string or as a date? In Ingres 10.2 there is the to_char() function which might be useful, eg: select to_char('now','YYYYMM');

Comment: @GJones its throwing an error E_US0B5A no such function as to_char

Comment: You're probably using an older version of Ingres in which case that function won't be available, sorry. You can check the ingres version with: select dbmsinfo('_version');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select varchar(date_part('year','01102016'))+ shift(varchar(100+date_part('mos',date('01032016'))),-1);`
Here is how it was done

Comment: Wow!  Seems like a lot of work.  Bet you're missing SQL Server now  :)

Comment: for sure its slower more uncomfortable